# Reading error messages at bootup

Tags: boot

I'm helping a friend load Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on an old Dell laptop.  I have it working, but there are several lines of errors that appear during boot up. They come up and disappear so quickly that it's impossible to read even one of them.  There's also a line that says something about getting some updated software.

How do I get to these errors and messages, or stop the process so I can at least read them?

Comment: I tried it, but I get back "no sch file or directory.  So perhaps the system log file is somewhere else.

Comment: You got me started.    I went to DASH and got the log file viewer.  I found the error messages and the instruction message.

Comment: Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that viewing the contents of the system log -

```
sudo more /var/log/messages
```

might just get you what you are after.

There is also the kernel ring buffer, at 
/var/log/dmesg
which can be viewed via paging commands (using `less`, and `more` [as in the above example]), or its most recent contents with just

```
sudo dmesg
```